# Solr: change default value of MaxFieldLength in <mainIndex>

Tags: coldfusion, solr, coldfusion-9, default-value

Is there a way to change the default `<mainIndex><maxFieldLength>` value in the `solarconfig.xml` file, so that when a Solr collection is created ALL collections will use the new value?

The default value of 10000 is okay for most applications, but most of the PDFs I am working with are over 100 pages. The client is concerned that the search results do not return EVERY PDF containing the given keywords. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that the `maxFieldLength` is limiting the indexing to just a fraction of the PDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `<maxFieldLength>` is restricting the number of tokens, not characters that are indexed. See - http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/maxFieldLength-td490843.html for a discussion around this.

**Update:**
I was incorrect previously, in order to change this value for all collections, you will need to add a property to your solr.xml file as shown in [Solr.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%20%28pre%205.x%29). That property can then be referenced in your solrconfig.xml file `<maxFieldLength>` setting in each core/collection.

However, I am not sure how this would be incorporated into the ColdFusion implementation as I am not familiar with how CF works. It may need to remain a manual process.

Comment: Thank you, Paige.  I changed the setting in core0/conf/solrconfig.xml, thinking that all future collection creation will have this setting.  But when I create a collection using CFCOLLECTION, it's still set to 10000.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a shot and report back.