# In solr, is there any limit of size to index data for text_general field type

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I have a log file about 300mb and i want to index that data on solr.But, my data field seems empty in some of documents.I suppose this problem arise because of Text_general 's size limit.Is there any limit on text_general.If there is , how much is it?

Comment: Can you provide sample of your schema.xml, sample data.

Comment: The fields shouldn't be empty, but you might be hitting the [`maxFieldLength` limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296356/solr-change-default-value-of-maxfieldlength-in-mainindex) if you're on a Solr-version <4.0, which by default limits fields to the first 10000 tokens.

Comment: As mentioned in the last comment there is a configuration for Lucene that you can change. You can see this reply from Yonik Seeley in the mail archives too: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/200807.mbox/%3Cc68e39170807220845t16b11d9bk8c19023c2067b171@mail.gmail.com%3E